# SSIS Multiple csv to multiple tables (with the same names)

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a SINGLE SSIS package (in Visual Studio 2013) that will:

1. Iterate through my 50+ csv files.
2. Find the corresponding table (csv files and the tables have the same names), truncate it, and then load the data from the source file.

Note that the files and tables have the same name.
Also, it is possible that the new csv files will be added to the source folder, with corresponding database tables created (i.e. the SSIS package is NOT required to create any new tables).

I have hit a wall many times I've tried to solve this before I decided to ask you for help - how do I go about this?

Comment: when you say you have hit a wall what specifically are you having trouble with?  Can you show us something you have tried so we can answer/help solve within your context?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, Matt. The issue is no longer actual. Many thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a foreach loop iterate through your files, and a script task that looks at the file name, and truncates and bulk inserts the file into the table of the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!. The issue is no longer actual. Many thanks and kind regards.